# Error in Mako: "expected %>", escaping %

Tags: mako

I'm currently writing Javascript in a mako file, and on one line, I have to check whether two strings are equal. The string I'm checking against has "<%text" within it, so I used to get an error saying there's no tag named text. I escaped that by adding a second % to get "<%%text". But now, I'm getting the following error.

```
SyntaxException: Expected: %> in file file.mako
```

What is the problem?

Comment: can you put up a simplified version of the template that has just enough content to create the problem?

Answer (score 0):

"<%" and "%>" are reserved symbols in Mako.  If they appear in your template, Mako will assume that you mean to escape a python code block.  Here is an example of what I mean:

```
"""
<%
  some_var = 'foo'
  other_var = '{0} bar'.format(some_var)
%>
"""
```

Take a look at http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/syntax.html#python-blocks for more details

Excuse the quotes, "<%" and "%>" are also reserved symbols in the Stack Overflow WYSIWYG editor.

If the Javascript variables you are comparing contain reserved symbols, you will have to find another way of comparing them.  Perhaps you could use the unicode entity for the percent sign:

For example:

```
if ('<%' == '<\u0025') {
    alert('success!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had a broken string variable which broke the logic, and fail on the un-related `<% ... %>`
Example:

```
<%
 variable = 'this won't work'
 #                  ^^^
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

"<%" and "%>" are reserved symbols in Mako. It is used to define "Python Blocks"

You can escape it by this: ${"escaped text"}

In your case:
${"<%"} or ${">%"}